# Dead Kernel : sift.detect(gray,None) The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically

Tags: python, sift

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('home.jpg')
gray= cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
sift = cv2.SIFT()
**kp = sift.detect(gray,None)**  #Kernel dies here
img=cv2.drawKeypoints(gray,kp)
cv2.imwrite('sift_keypoints.jpg',img)
```

Just want to learn SIFT but Mr.Kernel dies while executing sift.detect.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and fixed it by using `cv2.SIFT_create()` instead of `cv2.SIFT()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install opencv-contrib-python:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python --user
```